# OBIEE 12.2.1.2 Visual Analyzer - Data Format and Map(VA)

Tags: oracle, data-visualization, business-intelligence, analyzer, obiee

Is it possible to change the data format in VA? I.e. I do not want "Billions" to be displayed. 
[image]

Moreover, I want to deactive the Map [image]visualization. Is this somehow possible?

Ideas and suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Funny - I'm just fighting with Oracle about similar topics. Short version: The DVT charting engine is extremely black-boxed and has almost no config parameter exposed or documented. Yet.

Edit: regarding the maps at the moment it's all or nothing. You have VA or you don't.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your reply. Regarding the maps: is this visualization type then somehow connected to the geo/spatial data option of the oracle db? Or are they completely independent from each other?

Comment: Independent. You *can* use what's in the DB though of course